# Xamarin Forms FFImageLoading Image not showing

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, ffimageloading

I am trying to use `FFImageLoading` in one of our Xamarin Forms Projects but I am having some weird issues.

When I try to put `Sources="anyvalidimageurl"` on the XAML, I get this error:

> Invalid XAML: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: 'obj'

This is the XAML:

```
<ffimageloading:CachedImage HorizontalOptions="Center" 
            WidthRequest="300" 
            HeightRequest="300"
            DownsampleToViewSize="true"
            Source="http://myimage.com/image.png"
            x:Name="imgImage">
</ffimageloading:CachedImage>
```

I tried to load the image through code, but no image is shown on iOS.

Comment: Is your iOS project set to allow http requests?

Comment: <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
     <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key><true/>
</dict> IOS disable http resuqests by default

Answer (score 2):

You need to add this to your AppDelegate.cs

```
  public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        FFImageLoading.Forms.Touch.CachedImageRenderer.Init();
        var dummy = new FFImageLoading.Forms.Touch.CachedImageRenderer();

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

For more information see https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/55

Answer (score 0):

Did you miss to include CachedImageRenderer.Init(); in AppDelegate.cs